# Reduce visibility of stubs generated by Quick Fix in eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse

With Quick Fix, eclipse lets you generate stubs for methods in other classes when you write a call to a non-existent method. It always chooses to make such methods public even if a lower visibility such as package-private would be possible. Can I change this behavior?

- I haven't found a way to configure eclipse accordingly and I also haven't found an extension or patch doing this.
- Eclipse helps with selecting a different visibility after the code is generated (using the tab and arrow keys) but it's still annoying, and I tend to forget to "fix" the signatures as I use much more package-private than public methods.
- Same problem for generating other members or classes using Quick Fix.

NB. I find it problematic that eclipse promotes the unnecessary use of public elements. No wonder that people forget about package-private altogether, despite it being the default visibility when you don't specify an extra keyword.

Comment: This tool allows you to find the suspect and quick-fix http://www.ucdetector.org/ it may be useful for u!